# The colloquial use of the pronoun "you" followed by "adjectives"

Tags: word-usage, colloquialisms, offensive-language

Utterances like **you pig!**, **you bastard!** or **you silly!** are quite common but it is hard to find grammatical explanation about them as they are prevalent in the colloquialism.

I would be glad if somebody helped me to better understand the use of the pronoun **you** before **adjectives** and in what environments it usually appears. For example, can it be replaced by another expression, what are the common adjectives used with it, can it be used to praise?

Comment: What makes you think "pig" and "bastard" are adjectives?

Comment: Probably best seen as a special kind of verbless clause with an exclamatory meaning, comprising just pronoun+noun. The meaning is _You are a pig! / You are a bastard!_. Your example _You silly!_ with an adjective is probably just childish nonsense.

Comment: I gues when I was writing I had in mind sentences like "you fat" or "you silly" and I just missed the fact that nouns are the most common with this structure. My bad! Things are much more clear (should it be clearer?) now since a verbless clause explains its origin and it is easier to understand. Thanks, BillJ.

Comment: 'You (noun)!'' is not a colloquial structure.

Answer (score 1):

It’s just a special kind of noun phrase where a pronoun is described by a follow-on noun (or adjective being used like a noun).  The grammatical terms are dense and frankly over my head, but there is a discussion of this in [Foundations of Cognitive Grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=o5yDpuZL3iEC&pg=PA151) where it gives other examples like “we linguists” and “you three”.

> The personal pronouns are actually grounding predications; although they normally stand alone as nominals, we and you are occasionally elaborated by a head noun: we linguists; you bastard!”

So you can use it with a wide variety of nouns and pronouns.   While most of the common ones involving “you” that spring to mind are negative, they don’t have to be.  “You saint!” is just as valid as “You liar!”

As Low Powah pointed out, "you silly" doesn't really fit the pattern.  It's more something you'd say to a child, or in a joking childlike fashion.

Comment: You might want to mention that cases like “you silly” are fundamentally different in that they're simply (originally dialectal, mainly AAVE I'd say) verbal clauses that have had their verb deleted. “Gurl, you crazy!” and “You such a ho!” are both equivalent to “Girl, you're crazy” and “You're such a whore”, whereas “You idiot!” never had a verb and was never “*You're idiot!” (ungrammatical to boot). Also, while different in structure, certain phrases with _your_ function similarly: Your Majesty, Your Honour, Your Excellence, etc.

Comment: Huh. I'm surprised Langacker identifies the second noun as the head, predicated by the first. I would have parsed it as an appositive.

Answer (score 0):

"you pig" - The person being addressed displays mannerisms or hygiene comparable to what might be expected from a pig. Note that "pig" here is a noun, not an adjective.

"you bastard" - A general insult to the honesty or legitimacy of the addressed person. The word "bastard" used to mean a child of unknown parentage, or the son of a monarch who could not ascend legally. Note that "bastard" here is also a noun, although its actual meaning is much less clear than the noun definition might lead one to believe.

"you silly" - A playful, teasing kind of descriptor. This is incorrect grammar, and many native English speakers think it is funny or cute. I think that may be because young children tend to worry less about proper grammar, and so misusing words can be seen as child like.